# Scanning code doesn't work

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Okay so I am doing an assignment for a class in which I have to read the 4 colour bands on a resistor and determine its resistance value. In order to do this I wrote code first asking the user to input the letter which corresponded to a specific band colour. For example R corresponds to red. Here is the code I wrote:

```
char band1, band2, band3, band4;
float firstband, secondband, thirdband, fourthband;
float value1, value2, value3, value4, finvalue;
printf("Please enter the 1st band: ");
scanf("%c", &band1);
printf("Please enter the 2nd band: ");
scanf("%c", &band2);
printf("Please enter the 3rd band: ");
scanf("%c", &band3);
printf("Please enter the 4th band: ");
scanf("%c", &band4);
```

The problem is that the when the user is asked to input the letters the request gets jumbled up. It gives me this:

Please enter first band:

Please enter the second band: Please enter the third band:

Please enter the fourth band: Resistance is ...

Only the first band value and the third band value are read, the second and fourth are skipped. I can't seem to find the error in the code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you differentiate between black, brown, blue, green, and gray?

Comment: Code prompts "Please enter the 1st band:".  User enters `R` (for red) and then types the enter key  or `'\n'`.  `scanf("%c", &band1);` reads the `'R'` and `scanf("%c", &band2);` reads the `'\n'`.  2 keys typed.  2 keys read.  The "the second and fourth are skipped" is not so.  It is just that code read a `'\n'` into `band2`.

Answer (score 3):

You are feeding `scanf` references to single `char` variables. You seem to want to input strings, which are arrays of `char`.

Looks like this:

```
char aString[20];

printf("Enter a string, no more than 19 characters: ");
scanf("%s", aString);
```

It says "no more than 19 characters" because strings in C are null-terminated.

This is however just written in an easy way to understand. It's error-prone though. As pointed out in the comments, this would be more robust:

```
if (1 != scanf("%19s", aString))
{
    Handle_problem();
}
```

Comment: No, I needed characters because I used switch statements after to determine the value corresponding to the letter the user inputted.

Comment: So... you didn't give us enough information to help. It was very unclear from the code you posted what you needed.

Comment: Using `if (1 != scanf("%19s", aString)) Handle_problem();` would be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do any error checking or input clearing. As a result, the next `scanf` call "eats up" the invalid characters from the previous one resulting in the call seeming to be "skipped".

In order to fix this, you can use the following function to clear the input buffer (which is what `scanf` reads from first):

```
void clear_input() {
  int ch = 0;
  while(( ch = getchar) != '\n' && ch != '\0' && ch != EOF );
}
```

Also, it is a good idea to get into the habit of checking scanf's return value; this ensures valid input is given.:

```
int check = -1;
do {
  check = scanf( "%c", &variable );
  clear_input();
} while (check != 1);
```

An alternative to `scanf` if you only need a single character might be to use `getchar( void )`. `getchar()` obtains a single character from the user and returns the value of that character. Even if you take this route, you still have to clear the input buffer.